# Что выгоднее: динамический массив или заранее созданный?

Tags: c++, массивы, динамические-массивы

Допустим мне известно, что входных данных в массив будет от 1000 до 20000. В начале мне подаётся количество входных данных. Я могу заранее объявить массив длинной в 20000 и заполнять его, а могу по кол-ву входных данных создать динамический. Что более выгодно по скорости и по памяти динамически создающийся каждый раз массив или уже созданный определённого размера?

Comment: динамический, заранее созданный.

Comment: Еслибы была однозначность в этом вопросе, то  один из способов просто несуществовал бы

Comment: В случае простой пользовательской программы типа "зубочистка" (или "молоток" (программа, требования к которой не меняются, т.е. код не потребует сопровождения)), запускаемой на чем-то вроде десктопа или сервера -- без разницы. Поэтому используйте статический (меньше букв в программе) или даже в стеке (пожалуй тут будет микроскопический выигрыш в скорости)

Answer (score 3):

В принципе, единовременное создание массива - если оно не выполняется в цикле тысячи раз в секунду - по времени вы и не заметите.

А вот в системе с ограниченным ресурсом памяти тягать массив на 20000 значений заполненным только на 1000 - может оказаться накладным.

Так что зависит от того, где и как планируется использовать такой массив.

Как обычно - *"панацеи не существует"*...

Comment: Отличается ли время доступа к массиву, созданному на стеке и в куче?

Comment: *В общем случае* - нет. Это одна и та же физическая память, одинаково кэшируемая etc etc...

Answer (score 0):

Вобщем решил разобраться, а лучший способ для этого - эксперимент.

Для начала стоит сказать, что время которое я замерял у алгоритма имело погрешность и иногда было ОЧЕНЬ разным, да и на разных машинах оно по объективным причинам будет отличаться.

Вот начальный код:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
#include <ctime>
using namespace std;



int main()
{

  int const N = 20000;
    int arr[N];
    int start = clock();
    for(int i = 0; i < N; i++){
        arr[i] = i;
    }
    for(int i = 0; i < N; i++){
        arr[i] += 10000;
    }
    int end = clock();
    float time = end - start;
    cout << time / CLOCKS_PER_SEC << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Просто заранее создаю массив в 20000, а потом ещё раз прохожу и увеличиваю каждое значение на 10000(Зачем писать что то более сложное?).
Среднее время - 0.000455

Теперь будем проходить не по всем 20000, а только по 10000:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
#include <ctime>
using namespace std;



int main()
{

  int const N = 20000;
    int arr[N];
    int a = 10000;


    int start = clock();
    for(int i = 0; i < a; i++){
        arr[i] = i;
    }
    for(int i = 0; i < a; i++){
        arr[i] += 10000;
    }
    int end = clock();
    float time = end - start;
    cout << time / CLOCKS_PER_SEC << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Среднее время - 0.000236

Создаём динамический массив в 20000 и делаем тоже самое:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
#include <ctime>
using namespace std;



int main()
{

  int const N = 20000;
    int a = 20000;

    int *arr;
    arr = new int[a];
    int start = clock();
    for(int i = 0; i < a; i++){
        arr[i] = i;
    }
    for(int i = 0; i < a; i++){
        arr[i] += 10000;
    }
    delete [] arr;
    int end = clock();
    float time = end - start;
    cout << time / CLOCKS_PER_SEC << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

среднее время, чуть больше, чем у массива заранее объявленного с 20000 - 0.000500

Теперь динамический массив в 10000:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
#include <ctime>
using namespace std;



int main()
{

  int const N = 20000;
    int a = 20000;

    int *arr;
    arr = new int[a];
    int start = clock();
    for(int i = 0; i < a; i++){
        arr[i] = i;
    }
    for(int i = 0; i < a; i++){
        arr[i] += 10000;
    }
    delete [] arr;
    int end = clock();
    float time = end - start;
    cout << time / CLOCKS_PER_SEC << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Среднее время - 0.000248

Теперь я решил сыграть "по крупному" и сделал свой первый шаг (т.е заранее создал массив), только увеличив в его в 10 раз. И опять прошёлся по всем значениям. Среднее время - 0.004598
Динамический массив такого же размера дал результат в 0.004961

Из всего этого я для себя сделал вывод, что если массив испльзовать полсле наполнения только один раз то заранее объвленный - Ваш выбор.

Надо будет как нибудь проверить с большим числом использований массива...

Answer (score 0):

**Коротко:**

Лучше создать массив необходимой длины.

```
int size;
cin >> size;
int *array = new int[size];
```

**Пояснения:**

Очевидно что расход памяти будет меньше, чем если сразу создать большой.

Разница в быстродействии будет ничтожна.

Комп начнёт сильно тормозить если закончится оперативная память из-за использования swap, поэтому лучше не выгадывать наносекунды, которые тратятся на создание массива и выбрать решение, которое расходует существенно меньше памяти.